# How to track number of connections with ReverseProxy balancing

Tags: go, load-balancing

I'm trying to write some simple load balancer on Go. I'm using simple `http.Server` and `httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy` like so:

```golang
func main() {
  ...
  server := http.Server{
    Addr: ":8080",
    ConnState: connStateHook,
    Handler: http.HandlerFunc(loadBalance),
  }
}
```

HandlerFunc is as follows:

```golang
func loadBalance(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  // let's imagine I have a hardcoded proxy to simplify things
  serverURL, _ := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
  proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(serverURL)
  proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

So whenever request will be sent to my `localhost:8080` it'll be proxied to `127.0.0.1:5000`. 
My goal is to handle how many active request's are handled by that proxy endpoint. I know there is `http.Server.ConnState` hook which allows you to track state of http request and fire "callbacks".

I've made a simple function to store the number of connections in global variable:

```golang
var connectionsAmount int

func connStateHook(connection net.Conn, state http.ConnState) {
  if state == http.StateActive {
    connectionsAmount = connectionsAmount + 1
  } else if state == http.StateIdle {
    connectionsAmount = connectionsAmount - 1
  } else if state == http.StateClosed {
    connectionsAmount = connectionsAmount - 1
  }
}
```

It works pretty well until I add additional N endpoints, because now I can't pair a request with specific proxy server. 
And I want to track this number, let's say, in `Endpoint struct`:

```golang
type Endpoint struct {
  URL *url.URL
  Proxy *httputil.ReverseProxy
  ActiveConnections int
}
```

In what way I can implement such tracking?

Comment: Add it to `loadBalance`. It's doing all the work and it knows what endpoint it's sending the request to. Before `proxy.ServeHTTP`, increment the account for whatever you're sending the request to, and after `proxy.ServeHTTP`, decrement it.

Comment: This also fixes the issue with your current code where any keepalive connection that idles out will give a net -1 (+1 when it goes active, -1 when it goes idle, then -1 again when it gets closed) which will eventually add up and give you negative total active connection counts.

Comment: @Adrian thanks, it works exactly like I wanted. Also, is there any drawbacks? If I'll want to run balancer on the prod at the end – is it ok to keep your approach?

Comment: It would have an issue that your current code also has - it's racy. To avoid race conditions you'd want to use either `sync` or `sync/atomic`. Or you could take a look at `expvar`, which would both take care of the race condition and make it easier to expose your metrics.

Comment: @Adrian `expvar` is awesome, thanks for suggestion.